# Substitution of Differentials without Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I have a question regarding substitution of differentials when no integral is present. A few days ago, I asked a question on the physics site, but the question I posted has evolved into a math question that I feel is more fitting here. The original post can be found here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/341596/bounds-of-integration-with-respect-to-something-that-is-not-time

As explained in that post, I was confused about the bounds of integration for a certain function. Specifically, I was confused as to why the bounds were $\int_{R+a}^{R-a}dr$ as opposed to $\int_{R-a}^{R+a}dr$. I learned that this was a result of substitution: the $dr$ was substituted in for the $dx$, and the bounds in terms of $x$ were transformed into $R+a$ and $R-a$ for $r$. I am still confused about this, however.

I am used to performing substitutions when integrals are present (for example, in u-substitution). However, Feynman makes a substitution for $dx$ before any integral is used. My question is, how would one know that the new equation in terms of $dr$ came from another equation (in terms of $dx$)? If I were just given the equation with $dr$, I would make the bounds of integration: $\int_{R-a}^{R+a}dr$ (low to high), but knowing the original equation in terms of $dx$, this is wrong. How are mathematicians able to keep track of all these substitutions and how they affect the bounds (for example, what happens if there were more substitutions; how would one keep track of all of those)? Thank you!

Comment: By being as mechanic as possible: The formula is  $\int_{a}^{b}f(g(x))g'(x)dx=\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(t)dt$, where $t=g(x)$ is the change of variable. So if you start with $\int_{M}^{N}f(t)dt$ and you are changing variables using $t=g(x)$, then the new integral should be $\int_{g^{-1}(M)}^{g^{-1}(N)}f(g(x))g'(x)dx$. In this case $M=g(a)$, therefore $a=g^{-1}(M)$, and $N=g(b)$ therefore $b=g^{-1}(N)$.

Comment: So, do mathematicians typically include the integral from the start? Feynman does not write in the integral until the end.

Comment: What is the start and what is the end? Like when you are planning to do many changes of variable to compute and integral?

Comment: The equation starts with $dW = -\frac{Gm'dm}{dr}$ and ends with $W = -\frac{Gm'm}{R}$

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with change of variable. It is just about orientation, where you re choosing to put your zero potential energy. He is putting it at $r=\infty$. This is **just a convention, no math**. You can put the zero anywhere you like. The integral is then from $r=\infty$ to $0$, so it is really $\int_{\infty}^{0}$. There is no mass everywhere in that interval. The mass only counts in the interval from $R+a$ to $R-a$. That's all. Put your zero at $r=0$ and the order reverses. The sign of the resulting potential energy accounts for the different choice.

Comment: Substitutions in differential equations where no integral sign is present are standard. But I wonder why your question doesn't give the example you're asking about?

Comment: See [Why choose a convention where gravitational energy is negative?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy#Why_choose_a_convention_where_gravitational_energy_is_negative.3F) .